# Grails Email Confirmation Plugin Assumes Context Path

Tags: email, grails

I'm trying to use the [Grails Email Confirmation Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/email-confirmation), but my application is designed to run at the root application context.  It runs at `localhost:8080/` rather than at `localhost:8080/appname`.  The plugin sends a confirmation link that looks like `localhost:8080/appname/confirm/YbL4DRWapJjF...`.  When I remove `/appname`, the link works perfectly.

Does anyone know of a way to either configure the plugin to not include the appname in the link or to map `/appname/confirm/{id}` to `/confirm/{id}`

Comment: I have it working with a redirect (see answer below) but it's a hack job if you ask me.  If anyone knows how to configure the Email Confirmation plugin to omit the application name from the context path, I would appreciate the help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't my favorite solution (see comments in the original question).

I added the following url mapping...

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
        ...
        "/appname/confirm/$id?"(controller: "user", action: "confirm")
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in the user controller, I added the following method...

```
@Secured(["ROLE_USER","ROLE_ANONYMOUS"])
def confirm (String id) {
    redirect(uri: "/confirm/$id")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried setting grails.serverURL in config.groovy?